# Not receiving output from json-parser in python

Tags: python, json, parsing, csv, output

This is incredibly basic: I had successfully used python for parsing json files in a single directory several months ago. But now I can't figure out how I tweaked it (a teammate came up with the code) so that I can get the data into a more useable csv format.

At the moment, I'm getting zilch when using Python Launcher or Terminal.

What the parser looks like:

```
import codecs
import json
import os
import sys
 try:
    import unicodecsv as csv
    except ImportError:
    import csv

    OUTPUT_FILE = 'output.csv'


def process_file(infile, writer):
    print('Processing file: %s' % infile)
    with codecs.open(infile, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        data = json.load(infile)
            for item in data:
                _id = item['id']
                description =  item['description']
                for gov in item['source']:
                    gov_id = gov['name']
                    for source in item['secondarySource']:
                        source_id = source['sourceId']
                            name = source['name']
                            party = source['party']
                            writer.writerow([_id, description, gov_id, source_id, name, party])


def process_files_in_directory(directory, outfile):
     with codecs.open(outfile, 'w') as outfile:
         writer = csv.writer(outfile)
         writer.writerow(["id", "description", "branch", "sourceID", "name", "party"])
         for f in os.listdir(path):
             if f.endswith('.json'):
                 process_file(f, writer)

USAGE = """
Usage:

            python json_parser.py <source_directory> [<output_file>]

            Where source_directory is path to directory with input JSON files.
            output_file is optional -- defaults to %s
            File names must end with .json
            """ % OUTPUT_FILE


if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        directory = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        print(USAGE)
        sys.exit(0)
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        outfile = sys.argv[2]
    else:
        outfile = OUTPUT_FILE
    process_files_in_directory(directory, outfile)
```

Comment: have you run it as a script passing in args?

Comment: No, I haven't... how would one go about doing that?

Comment: Sincerest apologies in advance for the greenness of it all!

Comment: don't worry about it, the usage is specified towards the end of the file, `python json_parser.py <source_directory> [<output_file>]` so call the file `json_parser.py` make sure you are in the same directory as you have saved it in then run it with `python json_parser.py path_to_source_dir`, the output_file is optional. Just make sure the source dir has your json files

Comment: Thanks. So I've edited this line:
    `directory = "/Users/..." `

And now I'm getting an error reading in Terminal saying that the first JSON file it encountered doesn't exist..

Comment: you don't need to edit anything, just run it as a script from the command line as above, i.e `python json_parser.py /home/user/Documents`

Comment: @jessica11 - Another thing to note is that `os.listdir` returns a list of items relative to the directory you pass in.  That can (and probably is) different from where ever you run the script from.  So, for example, `os.listdir("/some-dir")` might return `["one.json", "two.json"]`.  When you pass each of those into `process_file()`, it can't find it.  One fix is to use `process_file(os.path.join(path, f), writer)`.  Depending on how everything is called, you might need `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, f), writer)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has some formatting issues.  I'm not sure if they are related to the issues... here's a new version of your script.  The basic idea works, but you might want to format the CSV output to make it even more readable.  To prove this works I've run this from the command-line with:

```
python stackoverflow\junk.py stackoverflow\mydir
```

Where `stackoverflow\mydir` has two files: `one.json` and `two.json`.

The code below includes the fix from my comment above

```
import codecs
import json
import os
import sys

try:
    import unicodecsv as csv
except ImportError:
    import csv

OUTPUT_FILE = 'output.csv'


def process_file(infile, writer):
    print('Processing file: %s' % infile)
    with codecs.open(infile, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        data = json.load(infile)
        for item in data:
            _id = item['id']
            description = item['description']
            for gov in item['source']:
                gov_id = gov['name']
                for source in item['secondarySource']:
                    source_id = source['sourceId']
                    name = source['name']
                    party = source['party']
                    writer.writerow([_id, description, gov_id, source_id, name, party])


def process_files_in_directory(directory, outfile):
    with codecs.open(outfile, 'w') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerow(["id", "description", "branch", "sourceID", "name", "party"])
        for f in os.listdir(directory):
            if f.endswith('.json'):
                process_file(os.path.join(directory, f), writer)

USAGE = """
Usage:

            python json_parser.py <source_directory> [<output_file>]

            Where source_directory is path to directory with input JSON files.
            output_file is optional -- defaults to %s
            File names must end with .json
            """ % OUTPUT_FILE

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        directory = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        print(USAGE)
        sys.exit(0)
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        outfile = sys.argv[2]
    else:
        outfile = OUTPUT_FILE
    process_files_in_directory(directory, outfile)
```

Comment: Thanks @mtik00; I'll give it a go— honestly, I'm expecting about an 8-10mb csv file, so maybe I've just been really impatient on getting results. Wouldn't be the first time

Comment: At least it's easy enough to figure out if the script is still running in the Terminal... you won't get a prompt again until it's finished.  You'll most likely also see the output file's size increase periodically (as the OS flushes the data).